# PHP script successfully creating tables in MySQL but not adding data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote a php loop to parse JSON data and create and input it into MySQL tables. The problem is that the tables are created successfully, and I do not receive any of the error messages I built in particularly the one about not being able to add JSON data to the table (this is clearly where the issue is). Any idea what's preventing the script from inputting the data into MySQL?

```
// Create Table to Hold JSON

$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$value}_GAMES ( ".  // Creating a new table for each team
    "nfl_game_id INT NOT NULL, ".
    "team VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "opponent VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "totfd INT NOT NULL, ".
    "totyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ryds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pen INT NOT NULL, ".
    "penyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "trnovr INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pt INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptavg INT NOT NULL, ".
    "PRIMARY KEY ( nfl_game_id ));";

$retval = mysql_query($sql, $con); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $retval)
{
die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Table created successfully\n';


// Process JSON Data

$data = json_decode($result, true); // Decode JSON

foreach($data as $row)
{
$game = $row['nfl_game_id'];
$team = $row['team'];
$opponent = $row['opponent'];
$totfirstdown =$row['totfd'];
$totyds = $row['totyds'];
$pyds = $row['pyds'];
$ryds = $row['ryds'];
$pen = $row['pen'];
$penyds = $row['penyds'];
$trnovr = $row['trnovr'];
$pt = $row['pt'];
$ptyds = $row['ptyds'];
$ptavg = $row['ptavg'];

// Insert data into team-specific table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$value}_GAMES (nfl_game_id, team, opponent, totfd, ".
"totyds, pyds, ryds, pen, penyds, trnovr, pt, ptyds, ptavg)".
"VALUES('$game', '$team', '$opponent', '$totfirstdown', '$totyds',".
"'$pyds', '$ryds', '$pen', '$penyds', '$trnovr', '$pt', '$ptyds', ".
"'$ptavg')";
$ret_val = mysql_query($sql,$con); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $ret_val)
{
    die('Could not add JSON data to table: ' . mysql_error());
}
}

mysql_close($con); // Close Connection

}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: No error. But when I try to SELECT from any of the tables created by the script, there's no data - which brings up the question of why this error message isn't kicking in:

    if(! $ret_val)
{
    die('Could not add JSON data to table: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: Did you checked whether the connected user has the insert privilege?

Comment: Yes, I do have insert privilege

Answer (score 0):

Try this Its Working for me
You have to use $retval instead of $result
close your for each loop before query
Try below code

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE GAMES ( ".  
    "nfl_game_id INT NOT NULL, ".
    "team VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "opponent VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, ".
    "totfd INT NOT NULL, ".
    "totyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ryds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pen INT NOT NULL, ".
    "penyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "trnovr INT NOT NULL, ".
    "pt INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptyds INT NOT NULL, ".
    "ptavg INT NOT NULL, ".
    "PRIMARY KEY ( nfl_game_id ));";

$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $retval)
{
die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Table created successfully\n';

// Process JSON Data

$data = json_decode($retval, true); //You have to use $retval instead of $result

foreach($data as $row)
{

$game = $row['nfl_game_id'];
$team = $row['team'];
$opponent = $row['opponent'];
$totfirstdown =$row['totfd'];
$totyds = $row['totyds'];
$pyds = $row['pyds'];
$ryds = $row['ryds'];
$pen = $row['pen'];
$penyds = $row['penyds'];
$trnovr = $row['trnovr'];
$pt = $row['pt'];
$ptyds = $row['ptyds'];
$ptavg = $row['ptavg'];
} //close your for each loop over here
// Insert data into team-specific table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO GAMES (nfl_game_id, team, opponent, totfd, ".
"totyds, pyds, ryds, pen, penyds, trnovr, pt, ptyds, ptavg)".
"VALUES('$game', '$team', '$opponent', '$totfirstdown', '$totyds',".
"'$pyds', '$ryds', '$pen', '$penyds', '$trnovr', '$pt', '$ptyds', ".
"'$ptavg')";

$ret_val = mysql_query($sql,$conn); // Execute SQL Code
if(! $ret_val)
{
    die('Could not add JSON data to table: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close($conn); // Close Connection
```

Comment: For error message receive you can comment the query in above answer and try you will get error message as well that "Could not add JSON data to table"

Answer (score 0):

json_decode() function returns std object type, not array.

so use

```
$game = $row->nfl_game_id;
```

instead of

```
$game = $row['nfl_game_id'];
```

Comment: json_decode($var, true) will return an array. json_decode($var) will return an object.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed true part :(